# read data of specific length from a specific position ios

Tags: ios, nsfilehandle

I have the following code for reading a file in length of specific size:

```
  int chunksize = 1024;
  NSData*  fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:URL];
  NSString* fileName = [[message.fileURL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
  NSString*  extension = [[message.fileURL pathExtension] lastPathComponent];
  NSFileHandle*  fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[self retrieveFilePath:fileName andExtension:extension]];
  file=@"test.png";

    int numberOfChunks =  ceilf(1.0f * [fileData length]/chunksize); //it s about 800

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfChunks; i++)
    {
        NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:chunksize];
        ....//some code
    }

// read a chunk of 1024 bytes from position 2048
 NSData *chunkData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1024 fromPosition:2048];//I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS!!
```

Comment: What's with the `float`s ? (`ceilf()` and `1.0f`)?

Comment: in order to retrive the total number of chunks in a file and to convert the real number into a integer one i've used that syntax

Comment: There is no need to involve floating point at all.

Comment: do you have a better solution?:)

Comment: I think this will work: `int numberOfChunks =  ([fileData length] / chunksize) + (([fileData length] % chunksize) ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the file pointer to the offset you want to read from:

```
[fileHandle seekToFileOffset:2048];
```

And then read the data:

```
NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1024];
```

Be aware that errors are reported in the form of `NSExceptions`, so you'll want some `@try/@catch` blocks around most of these calls.  In fact the use of exceptions to report errors means I often make my own file-access functions to ease their use; for example:

```
+ (BOOL)seekFile:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandle
        toOffset:(uint32_t)offset
           error:(NSError **)error
{
    @try {
        [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
    } @catch(NSException *ex) {
        if (error) {
            *error = [AwzipError error:@"Failed to seek in file"
                                  code:AwzipErrorFileIO
                             exception:ex];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: a very nice way of explaining this. Thank you very much!! Could I ask you why did you choose to use + in front of the [self seekFile:fileHandler toOffset:2048 error:error] method? You want to make it a public one?

Comment: It's because that's a utility class which is used from everywhere in the code.  The class holds no state and simply provides utility functions.

Comment: That's a class to create custom `NSError` objects, specific to the problem domain.  You can just use the base `NSError` methods or create your own error-generating functions.